# "Boolean" does not create a new faces

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I cant figured out why a cylinder make a hole in my geometry, when it supposed to be a notch? Why there isn't new faces?[image]

Answer (score 2):

Boolean modifiers are known to cause issues when dealing with non-manifold and/or curvy geometry.

I can't say for sure what exactly what is causing the issue from your screenshot, but I'd guess it has to do with how you constructed it, seeing that your object is named as a *plane* in the outliner.

Applying a *Solidify Modifier* before the *Boolean Modifier* should fix your issue.